# How to reuse variables in the select statement of mysql

Tags: mysql, variables

I would like to use mysql variables to prevent same statements. In the following example i would like to sum the salary of an each employee and also sum it twice times. Of course the second column is wrong.

```
MariaDB [Messdaten]> select * from t;
+----+----------+--------+
| id | employee | salery |
+----+----------+--------+
|  1 |       10 |   1000 |
|  2 |       10 |   2000 |
|  3 |       20 |   3000 |
|  4 |       20 |   4000 |
+----+----------+--------+
4 rows in set (0.000 sec)



MariaDB [Messdaten]> select employee, @x:=sum(salery), 2*@x from t group by employee;
+----------+-----------------+-------+
| employee | @x:=sum(salery) | 2*@x  |
+----------+-----------------+-------+
|       10 |            3000 | 14000 |
|       20 |            7000 | 14000 |
+----------+-----------------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Of course i could use `select employee, sum(salery), 2*sum(salery)` but in my real use case the statements are very big and therefore bad readable.
What ist going wrong and if this is a gap of mysql are there some workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery like so to get the correct result while only summing (or executing a more complex statement) once

```
SELECT 
    employee, 
    totalSalary, 
    totalSalary*2 AS doubleSalary
FROM (
    SELECT 
        employee, 
        sum(salary) AS totalSalary
    FROM employees 
    GROUP BY employee
) AS employeeSalaries;
```

The unexpected variable behaviour is described in the MySQL docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html).

> HAVING, GROUP BY, and ORDER BY, when referring to a variable that is assigned a value in the select expression list do not work as expected because the expression is evaluated on the client and thus can use stale column values from a previous row.

Comment: thanks, that's a great idee and it works.but it would still be interesting to find out why mysql behaves so strangely with variables

Comment: upps my mistake, it should be "salary" not "salery"

Comment: I updated my answer with why variables behave this way